# Extracting Hebrew text from an OpenDocument Text Bible

Tags: python-2.7, odf

I'm trying to extract Hebrew text from a Bible in OpenDocument Text (odt) format with the following code:

```
from odf import text, teletype
from odf.opendocument import load

textdoc = load("Heb-OT.odt")
texts = textdoc.getElementsByType(text.P)
alltext=teletype.extractText(texts[0])
print alltext
```

This does not print anything
I don't know what's wrong.
The document is very long (1000 pages) but I need to search it all.

Comment: I found the code that seems to correspond to the implementation of teletype here:http://bit.ly/1pfgWn7 but it does not help me. here is the original document I use: http://bit.ly/1Ll99hs (converted to odt by LibreOffice)

Comment: Apparently the text extraction stops at newline... I still don't know how to change that

Comment: I converted the whole file to utf-8 txt with odt2txt then I have been able to extract characters with codecs.open ... but if someone can answer the question I am still interested just for knowledge.